# Makking appendices doesn’t work

Tags: appendices

I’m writing my thesis, and I seeming to be having a problem with the appendix.

Here’s an MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{My first appendix}

My first appendix sentence.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

When I run this document with WinEdit, I get an error:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of posting the screen shot of the error, can you please post the text of the error in code formatting? It will make it much easier to read.

Comment: Also, please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which can produce the error. This will be a small, complete document rather than fragments of code which includes much of no relevance to the problem. Also, you are loading packages twice.

Comment: Where is the text of the error in code formatting ?

Comment: The code posted still doesn't compile, because the `Intro` file is missing. I assume that’s where the `\begin{document}` command is hiding, because it isn’t in the code above.

Comment: you are right. I forgot to copy "\begin{document}"

Comment: Fairly sure I stripped it back to just the problem packages, but revert/edit if I missed something.

Comment: Thank you. I think my problem depends this package: \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

Comment: The text of the error is `! Undefined control sequence. <argument>...` It would be helpful if you copied this out of the IDE and posted it into your question with the code formatting instead of posting the screen shot. The screen shot has a tiny font and is difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

I have already fixed the problem. I'm using portuguese babel, and the word appendice in portuguese use this letter: Ê
But, I changed the name appendice to annex. Now, I don't have problems. Actually, I prefer the word annex than appendice.